# Both S3ResponseError SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, boto

I am trying to download data from S3 using Apache Spark. Trying to lookup the bucket. I can lookup the bucket unsaid AWS CLI.
I am facing the following error while connecting AWS S3 using Boto Library.

My Code:

```
conn = S3Connection('yay', 'xxx',calling_format = OrdinaryCallingFormat())
bucket = Bucket(conn, 'exports.lomy.t')
list = bucket.list('PATH')
```

Error

```
Tue, 28 Jun 2016 20:31:51 GMT
/exports.lomys.t/</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>d4utF8Kab3ESrzMLlwM2ilc5chA=</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>47 45 54 0a 0a 0a 54 75 65 2c 20 32 38 20 4a 75 6e 20 32 30 31 36 20 32 30 3a 33 31 3a 35 31 20 47 4d 54 0a 2f 65 78 70 6f 72 74 73 2e 6c 6f 63 61 6c 79 74 69 63 73 2e 74 2d 7a 2f</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>72D199C86E9D6E10</RequestId><HostId>36pedNVg9XFQSHhr7Am3YUe4wypff7+bEHi249eQJllhHOwrK8ha37M7er8PJdTUQsxQIcGnmxk=</HostId></Error>
```

I see couple of solutions which says match the signature. But how? I think following is the signature I am sending `d4utF8Kab3ESrzMLlwM2ilc5chA=`

1) How to find the signature expected?
2) How to get around this issue :)

If anyone has already resolved the issue it will be great help.

Thanks in advance ,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved after I disconnect the corporate network.
It was our proxy which was blocking.